# I want to pass my fetch results to setState. When I console.log(setUserApartment) it doesn't show the data from foundApartment. How can I setState?

Tags: reactjs

```js
import {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react"
import apiUrl from "../../../apiConfig"

const UserApartments = (props) => {

    // get an apartment by Id
    const [userApartment, setUserApartment] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
      getUserApartment()
    }, [])

    const getUserApartment = () => {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${props.user.token}`
        },
      }
      console.log('USER APARTMENTS', setUserApartment)

      fetch(`${apiUrl}/apartments/user/${props.user._id}`, requestOptions)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(foundApartments => {
          console.log('THESE ARE THE USER APARTMENTS', foundApartments)
          console.log('USER APARTMENTS SET TO STATE', setUserApartment)
          setUserApartment(foundApartments)
        }, [])
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

My console log for foundApartments shows **{apartments: Array(2)}**, then **apartments: Array(2)**, then **0:{_id: '61df0f312c26cb6a5d0db105', owner: '61df0f162c26cb6a5d0db100'}**, then **1: {_id: '61e0bdf21053bb04c6776167', owner: '61df0f162c26cb6a5d0db100'}**, **length: 2**. Which is what it should show as that user has only created 2 apartment listings. I want to setState so I may use this component as a prop for editing user apartments. Should I pass the data from my fetch call to setUserApartment? Should the console log for foundApartments and setUserApartment show the same information if data is passed correctly to setUserApartment? I'm a new developer so please let me know if more context is needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're console logging the function to set the state. You need to console log the state to see what's in it rather than the function to set the state.

```
console.log('USER APARTMENTS', userApartment)
```

instead of

```
console.log('USER APARTMENTS', setUserApartment)
```

Comment: Thanks! I console logged the state and it has the correct data in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting state correctly via setUserApartment(foundApartments).
If you add the state value to the JSX returned by the component:

```
<>{userApartment}</>
```

you'll see it.
You could also test this by adding another effect (just for testing purposes) that will run whenever the state changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("state has changed", userApartment);
}, [userApartment]);
```

Note that the state value is asynchronously set, so you can't reliably print it to the console straight after setting it.

The first value you are printing

```
console.log('THESE ARE THE USER APARTMENTS', foundApartments)
```

will print the correct value returned by your fetch request.

Now the other log:

```
console.log('USER APARTMENTS SET TO STATE', setUserApartment)
```

is printing the function passed to useEffect to set the state.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react"
import apiUrl from "../../../apiConfig"

const UserApartments = (props) => {

    // get an apartment by Id
    const [userApartment, setUserApartment] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
      getUserApartment()
    }, [])

    const getUserApartment = () => {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${props.user.token}`
        },
      }
      console.log('USER APARTMENTS', setUserApartment)

      fetch(`${apiUrl}/apartments/user/${props.user._id}`, requestOptions)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(foundApartments => {
          console.log('THESE ARE THE USER APARTMENTS', foundApartments)
          console.log('USER APARTMENTS SET TO STATE', userApartment)
          setUserApartment(foundApartments)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    const userApartmentList = userApartment ? userApartment.apartments.map((apartment) => {
          return <li > {
            apartment.title
          } < /li>}) : null
          console.log(userApartmentList)
          console.log('USER CREATED APT', userApartment)

          return (

            <
            div > {
              userApartmentList
            } <
            /div>

          )
        }

        export default UserApartments
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

After reading the response from David clarifying that state was being passed correctly and that I needed to console log useState instead of setState. I then mapped through userApartment and saved it to the variable userApartmentList. I used the ternary operator to handle the undefined map error I was getting. Then returned userApartmentList as JSX.